# How to return array with in loop by using return

Tags: php

I've no idea How to pass a variable in and array, How can I pass $query variable In foreach loop  with  using return

```
public function test($id){
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.SELF::TABLE_MEMBERS_CONTAINER. ' c
        LEFT JOIN '.SELF::TABLE_MEMBER.' m ON
        c.members_id = m.id
        LEFT JOIN '.SELF::TABLE_CONTAINER.' ct ON
        c.container_id = ct.id
        WHERE c.members_id =  '. $id . '  ORDER BY c.created_at  desc';
        $row = $this->query_rows( $sql );
    foreach ($row as $r ) {
        $i++;
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `'.SELF::TABLE_STATUS_CONTAINER.'` WHERE container_id = ' .$r['container_id'];
        $query = $this->query_rows( $sql );
        var_dump($query);
    }
    return array(
     'data'=>$row,
    );
}
```

I try to

```
return array(
 'data'=>$row,
 'query'=>$query,
);
```

when I var_dump inside loop it's return

```
bool(false)
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["container_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["title"]=>
    string(51) "teat"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["container_id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["title"]=>
    string(72) "te"at
  }
}
bool(false)
```

but when I var dump outside loop it's return just

bool(false)

Comment: Do a `var_dump(test(1))` and update your question with the output

Comment: ok i'll update  .

Comment: UPDATED MY QUESTION @MehdiBounya

Comment: Wait. you are not using `$r` in your loop at all? your logic is invalid, can you say what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: first i try to select data  in container then I want to get status in each container

Comment: my bad i updated my query now I use $r

Comment: And now, `$b` is not used, you may want to re-write your code.

Comment: ok i deleted $b alredy